# set uilabel's text that added in uitableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uilabel

In each uitableview cell, there's a button, and a uilabel, such as following code

```
ListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


[cell.UIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.UIButton.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.UILabel.text = @"0";
```

I want this, when I click the button, the uilabel.text at the same cell with the uibutton will add one, I click again, the uilabel.text will add one more, something like vote.

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
  NSInteger selectedRow = sender.tag;
}
```

so how can I change the uilabel's text? thanks.

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html and rename your variables and methods accordingly to make it easier for us to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @duci9y thanks for your suggesstion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why are you hardcoding the string `@"0"` as the label's text? If your goal is to track votes, you need to keep track of the current vote count in some data structure. Then you setup each cell based on the actual value from the data. This data can then be updated as the buttons are tapped.
2. Setting the button's tag to the `indexPath.row` will cause lots of problems if rows can be added, removed, or moved. There's a much better way to get the cell from the button without the need to bother with tags.

The following assumes you have an `NSMutableArray` ivar (`_votes`) in your class to act as a data source for the vote counts.

Now your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` becomes:

```
ListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell.UIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

NSNumber *votes = _votes[indexPath.row];    
cell.UILabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", votes];
```

Your button action becomes:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
    CGPoint pointInTable = [button convertPoint:CGPointMake(5, 5) toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.table indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];

    NSNumber *oldVote = _votes[path.row];
    NSNumber *newVote = @([oldVote intValue] + 1);
    _votes[path.row] = newVote;

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ path ] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: thanks, I had updated my code, and solved this problem.